# Generar coordenadas aleatorias en matriz en lenguaje c, como lo hago?

Tags: c

estoy haciendo un trabajo y me piden generar coordenadas aleatorias en una matriz 20x20, se divide en 4 cuadrantes, en cada cuadrante tengo que generar una posicion aleatoria, dentro de ese cuadrante, como puedo especificar que la generacion de los numeros aleatorios se queden en cada cuadrante con sus limites especificos? No se si se entendio mi duda

Comment: `v[x][y] -> x<10 & y<10; x>10 & y<10 `... etc

Comment: De esa forma generaria los topes de los distintos cuadrantes?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que tienes que hacer es ver cuales son los rangos válidos para cada cuadrante:

```
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9|10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
 0                             |
 1                             |
 2                             |
 3                             |
 4                             |
 5                             |
 6                             |
 7                             |
 8                             |
 9                             |
-------------------------------+-----------------------------
10                             |
11                             |
12                             |
13                             |
14                             |
15                             |
16                             |
17                             |
18                             |
19                             |
```

Así se ve claro que los rangos de cada cuadrante son:

| Cuadrante | X | Y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10-19 | 0-9 |
| 2 | 0-9 | 0-9 |
| 3 | 0-9 | 10-19 |
| 4 | 10-19 | 10-19 |

Por otro lado necesitas una fórmula para calcular un número aleatorio en un rango determinado:

```
int value = (rand() % (upper - lower + 1)) + lower;
```

Con esto ya lo tienes. Para, por ejemplo, generar unas coordenadas del primer cuadrante tendrías que hacer algo así:

```
int x = (rand() % (19 - 10 + 1)) + 10; // = (rand() % 10) + 10
int y = (rand() % (9 - 0 + 1)) + 0;    // = (rand() % 10)
```

Comment: Me explicarias como hiciste esa formula? Para saber bien por que esta cada variable en esa posicion?